# What ways exist to get system information in Windows 7 or 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, system-info

What ways exists for get system information in Windows 7 or 8?

For example we can use **`Msinfo32.exe`** and what is the best way for get system information?
(without any 3partyApps)

Comment: How about `systeminfo`! It displays detailed config info about a computer and its OS, including OS config, security info, product ID, and hardware properties. Try in `cmd` to analyse output.

Comment: I suggest you study the available commands for the Windows command prompt, there are too many to list that can pull system information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming `AnyFile.any` to `AnyFile.nfo` and running it will show you  the same as **MSInfo32.exe**.
**DXDiag.exe** will show more info about your videocard (that's DirectX Diagnostics tool).
**Compmgmt.msc** will show some info about your devices , service startup options, scheduled tasks, ... (also you can change them there).It's the same Computer Management which you can enter right-clicking `My Computer` and pressing `Manage`

Answer (score 1):

if you mean access Device manager etc. i.e. built in tools for system info. You can

Right click the 'invisible' start button and select from there
Hold down Windows Key and press Pause key for properties.

Comment: What does the "invisible" and mean and where is "Hold down Windows key"?? Please, clarify